# Talend - Main does not appear in link to Map

Tags: talend

Newbie question - I need to link a tFieInputLimited component to tMap, however "Main" does not appear (see below). What could be the reason?  I'm using a schema from the Metadata repository.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the Talend forum: it's a bug. Recreating the component solves the problem.